# Flutter banner does not fit

Tags: flutter, banner

I have a problem with banner widget. To demonstrate it I have made some demonstration code. What I want is to have a banner in the top right corner of a container, but it is ugly, as it overflows its child (pls. see the attached image).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Banner(
          message: "hello",
          location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            color: Colors.yellow,
            height: 100,
            child: Center(child: Text("Hello, banner!"),),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to play with the margin, but I still have this behavior even if margin set to 0.

How can avoid this 'banner overflow'?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just adding ClipRect to Op's code

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ClipRect(
          child: Banner(
            message: "hello",
            location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              color: Colors.yellow,
              height: 100,
              child: Center(child: Text("Hello, banner!"),),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Inverting the container and the banner

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

          height: 100,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Banner(
            message: "hello",
            location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Container(


              child: Center(child: Text("Hello, banner!"),),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Adding ClipRect to inverting Container and Banner

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ClipRect(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

          height: 100,
          color: Colors.yellow,

            child: Banner(
              message: "hello",
              location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Container(


                child: Center(child: Text("Hello, banner!"),),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html

Since you took the time and posted both sample code and an image, I decided to return the favor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

Comment: Well, you made a moderately detailed question

Comment: Adding ClipRRect does the trick. Thanks for the Answer

Answer (score 7):

Wrap your `Banner` inside `ClipRect` widget and remove the margin :

```
            ClipRect(
                      child: Banner(
                        message: "hello",
                        location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                          height: 100,
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Hello, banner!"),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider swapping the Banner and its child, Container. In your code, the banner is placed on the container. Instead, place it on the card. It should look like this

```
Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        color: Colors.yellow,
        height: 100,
        child: Banner(
          message: "hello",
          location: BannerLocation.topEnd,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Center(child: Text("Hello, banner!"),),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```